# MySQL group by week

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a large number of records with a transaction datetime field going back several years. I would like to do a comparative analysis between the same timespan this year and last. How can I group by week over a 3 month range?

I'm running into problems using the YEARWEEK and WEEK functions because of the day the year 2012 starts of versus the day 2011 starts on.

Given that I have records with datetimes everyday from Jan 1st to the current day, and records with the same datetimes from the prior year, how can I group by week so the output is sums with dates like: 01/01/2011, 01/08/2011, 01/15/2011, etc., and 01/01/2012, 01/08/2012, 01/15/2012, etc.?

My query so far is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(A.transaction_date, '%Y-%m-%d') as date,
    ROUND(sum(A.quantity), 3) AS quantity,
    ROUND(sum(A.total_amount), 3) AS amount,
    A.product_code, 
    D.fuel_type_code, 
    D.fuel_type_name, 
    C.customer_code, 
    C.customer_name 
FROM 
    cl_transactions AS A
INNER JOIN 
    card AS B ON A.card_number=B.card_number 
INNER JOIN 
    customer AS C ON B.customer_code=C.customer_code 
INNER JOIN 
    fuel_type AS D ON A.fuel_type=D.fuel_type_code 
WHERE 
    ((A.transaction_date >= DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 3 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01')) OR (A.transaction_date - INTERVAL 1 YEAR >=  DATE_FORMAT(NOW() - INTERVAL 15 MONTH, '%Y-%m-01') AND A.transaction_date <= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 YEAR))
GROUP BY 
    A.transaction_date, fuel_type_code;
```

I would essentially like something that achieves the following pseudo-query:

```
GROUP BY 
    STARTING FROM THE OLDEST DATE (A.transaction_date + INTERVAL 6 DAY)
```

Comment: It seems like you want MONTH and DAYOFMONTH() if you want the month and day to match.

Comment: @MarcusAdams: I've been looking into those date functions as well but am struggling with how to sum groups of seven days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started with an inner query using sqlvariables to build out from/to ranges for this year and last year of each respective start of year/month/day (ex: 2012-01-01 and 2011-01-01 respectively).  From that, I'm also pre-formatting the date for final output so you have ONE master date basis for display reflecting that of whatever the "this year" week would be.

From that, I do a join to the transaction table where the transaction date is BETWEEN the respective start of current week and start of next week.  Since date/time stamps include hour minute, 2012-01-01 by itself is implied as 12:00:00am (midnight) of the day.  and between will go UP TO 7 days later 12:00:00 am.  And that date will become the start date of the following week.

So, by joining on the date being between EITHER last yr or this yr time period, its the same group qualification.  So the field selection does a ROUND( SUM( IF() )) per respective last year or this year.  if the incoming transaction date is LESS than the current year's week start, then it must be a record from prior year, otherwise its for the current year.  So, respectively, add the value itself, or zero as it applies.

So now, you have the group by.  The week that it qualified for was already prepared from the inner query via "ThisYearWeekOf" formatted column, regardless of the otherwise computed "YEARWEEK()" or "WEEK()".  The date ranges took care of that qualification for us.

Finally, I added the fuel-type as a join and included that as the group by.  You have to group by all non-aggregate columns for proper SQL, although MySQL lets you get by by just grabbing the first entry for the given group if it is NOT so specified in group by.

To close, I DID include the information for the customer as you didn't have it in the group by and did not appear to be applicable... it would just arbitrarily grab one.  However, I've added it to the group by, so now your records will show at the per customer level, per product and fuel type, how much sales and quantity between this year and last.

```
SELECT
      JustWeekRange.ThisYearWeekOf,
      CTrans.product_code,
      FT.fuel_type_code, 
      FT.fuel_type_name, 
      C.customer_code, 
      C.customer_name,
      ROUND( SUM( IF( CTrans.transaction_date < JustWeekRange.ThisYrWeekStart, CTrans.Quantity, 0 )), 3) as LastYrQty,
      ROUND( SUM( IF( CTrans.transaction_date < JustWeekRange.ThisYrWeekStart, CTrans.total_amount, 0 )), 3) as LastYrAmt,
      ROUND( SUM( IF( CTrans.transaction_date < JustWeekRange.ThisYrWeekStart, 0, CTrans.Quantity )), 3) as ThisYrQty,
      ROUND( SUM( IF( CTrans.transaction_date < JustWeekRange.ThisYrWeekStart, 0, CTrans.total_amount )), 3) as ThisYrAmt,
   FROM 
      ( SELECT 
                 DATE_FORMAT(@ThisYearDate, '%Y-%m-%d') as ThisYearWeekOf,
                 @LastYearDate as LastYrWeekStart,
                 @ThisYearDate as ThisYrWeekStart,
                 @LastYearDate := date_add( @LastYearDate, interval 7 day ) LastYrStartOfNextWeek,
                 @ThisYearDate := date_add( @ThisYearDate, interval 7 day ) ThisYrStartOfNextWeek
            FROM 
                 (select @ThisYearDate := '2012-01-01',
                         @LastYearDate := '2011-01-01' ) sqlvars,
                 cl_transactions justForLimit
            HAVING
               ThisYrWeekStart < '2012-04-01'
            LIMIT 15 ) JustWeekRange

      JOIN cl_transactions AS CTrans
         ON    CTrans.transaction_date BETWEEN 
               JustWeekRange.LastYrWeekStart AND JustWeekRange.LastYrStartOfNextWeek
           OR  CTrans.transaction_date BETWEEN 
               JustWeekRange.ThisYrWeekStart AND JustWeekRange.ThisYrStartOfNextWeek

      JOIN fuel_type FT
         ON CTrans.fuel_type = FT.fuel_type_code

      JOIN card 
         ON CTrans.card_number = card.card_number 
         JOIN customer AS C 
            ON card.customer_code = C.customer_code 

   GROUP BY
      JustWeekRange.ThisYearWeekOf,
      CTrans.product_code,
      FT.fuel_type_code, 
      FT.fuel_type_name,
      C.customer_code, 
      C.customer_name
```

Comment: Holy cow, this is wonderful! Looks like it's working exactly as I need! Thank you so very much for taking the time to post this and explain in detail what you did. Much appreciated friend!

Comment: It's looking like it! I'm comparing things now and it seems to be adding up. Again, really appreciate your input.

Comment: @btl, only issue I could see as a throw-off is 2012 has Feb 29th..., so the following "start date" will be off by 1 day, but otherwise should stay in synch.